# Index.html issue & Vue

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, npm-build, index.html

So I'm using Vue 3 and Router. The site functions greatly when I do `npm run dev`. Now if I got this correct, I have to do `npm run build` for the site before I put it on something like netify right.

This created a dist folder, in the folder is an index.html file. It opens up blank?
I go to check the console log and see these errors

`Access to script at 'file:///Z:/assets/index-64361c69.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.`

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` x2

I'm pretty new to all this so do excuse me.

My question is what could be causing the issue for index.html to be blank?

vite.config.ts:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

dist > index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-64361c69.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-9b74bc40.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

index in the folder I do the npm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After this main folder with all the files and where I do the npm stuff, I have a src folder which contains
assets
components
router
views
App.vue
main.ts

Hope this helps.

Fixed my issues.

To get it to work with Netlify I just needed to create a file with:
called
`netlify.toml`
That contained this
`[build] command = "npm run build" publish = "dist"`

Comment: This is expected.  The `dist` directory is meant to be served by an HTTP server. It will not work if you open `dist/index.html` directly over `file://` protocol. You can preview the production build with `npm run preview` if needed.

Comment: Okay doing `npm run preview` worked. But I lost the images that I have in my folders. Might be how I have everything set up lol. That stuff is in files called projectFiles.ts.
So if that worked, how would I got about for something like Netify - if you know?

Comment: Netlify is exactly the type of service `dist` assets are meant to be served from.  Follow their documentation and you shouldn't have to do anything to the actual files themselves other than upload.

Comment: With Netlify I have tried to launch up a site. But it popped up with an error, if I do `npm run build` then it will just be a blank vite page. Should I do that as `npm run preview`. I'll have a look at thair documentation. I saw a video and it looked simple for the guy to just use his GitHub account which I was aiming to do.

Comment: I managed to get it to work on Netify buy creating a file called `netlify.toml` with:
`[build]
command = "npm run build"
publish = "dist"`